# Laravel 5.2 eager loading no working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

Heres what i am doing.

```
$question = ForumQuestion::where('link',$ques)->with('answers')->first();
$answers = $question->answers;
$answers->load('user');
//return $answers;
return view('forum.question', compact('question','answers'));
```

the `$answers->load('user');`  eager loads corresponding user of the answer.

```
public function user()
    {
        if ($this->user_type == 'student') {
            return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'user_id');
        }else{
            return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'user_id');
        }
    }
```

But problem is $this->user_type gets some kind of static. If my first answer has `user_type = 'teacher'` then in every query it assumes as it is `teacher` even though it changes some time to `student`.
Why it is static? If I don't eager load it works well.

Comment: Why don't you try to do nested eager loading `$question = ForumQuestion::where('link',$ques)->with('answers.user')->first();` this will get all your answers with users eager loaded

Comment: @FabioAntunes nested eager loading will result in null `user` as at the time of nested eager loading queries are build first then executed. This results in $this to null and hence there would not be `$this->user_type` which makes if statement always false and as a result wrong or null user.

Comment: That's because you are defining your relationship in the wrong way, take a look at [polymorphic-relations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your eager loading into two different categories instead of putting everything together into the user function

```
public function student() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'user_id');  
    }

public function teacher() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

and just if you really want to do an if statement, call it from a different function such as user. Hope that helps.

Comment: I know this will work but is this really a good answer? The queries will be doubled. as the user_id either belongs to teacher or student and hence one of them will be extra queried.